# JSTL - Assign list content into an array

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jstl

I have list of users and I want to assign each user into an index of array:

```
<%
    User users[] = new User[n];
    pageContext.setAttribute("users", users);      
%>
```

Now:

```
<c:forEach items="${usersList}" var="user">   
     // here I want to assign each user into an array index like:
     // users[index] = user               
 </c:forEach>
```

At the end I want to access each index of array manually. Something like below:

```
  <p><c:out value="${users[0].getName()}" /></p>
```

I know above is not correct, can some one help how can I achieve this via jstl? Thanks.

P.S: Please be noticed that I want to access the array by index manually.

Comment: How come you want to "assign each user into an array index" ? You're iterating the `users` array and assigning the next `user` item to the next index of the array... I don't get it...

Comment: Its just an example, because I want to get some properties of different users into a long index.jsp file.

Comment: The best I think you can do is initialize a `String[]` as `<c:set var="users" scope="request" value="${fn:split(usersList, ',')}"></c:set>`

Comment: Why are you mixing scriptlets and JSTL? You should either do this in the controller, or if you are using only scriptlets and cannot change it, just assign it to `usersList` using a `for` loop.

Comment: Yeah, but I don't want to put all html tags inside the loop, thats why I want to get indexes of the array manually.

Comment: Why do you want to take users from a list and put them in a array?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `varStatus` to get index in the loop

```
<c:forEach items="${usersList}" var="user" varStatus="status">
Index: ${status.index}
</c:forEach>
```